# PHP fopen won't append file extension when function in name

Tags: php, file, append, fopen, file-extension

I'm trying to timestamp a file after the time its created and then add extension :

```
$file_name = "reports/".date('m-d-Y_g:ia').".txt";
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'w');
fwrite($fp, "Did not return any results posted in the past week");
fclose($fp);
```

its returns file with no extension , any idea?
Thanks

Comment: the break tags aren't throwing a parse error?

Answer (score 1):

Found out why , it didnt accept " : " in the name .

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an example of the filename it actually creating, but am assuming it stops at the `:` character. It should work if you remove the `:` from the filename.

[See this Wikipedia page in reference to filenames.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)